# IAM policy for limiting AWS API Gateway over stages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have an API gateway with different stages (**prod** and **dev**), one for production and latter for development.

In-order to restrict access and deployments to **prod** stage, I have set following IAM policy for a dev user,

```
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "execute-api:*",
            "apigateway:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/6mvx7om366/stages/dev",
            "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/6mvx7om366/stages",
            "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis",
            "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/6mvx7om366",
            "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/6mvx7om366/deployments",
            .....
            ....
         ]
      }
```

where `6mvx7om366` is the API id.

This shows the **prod** stage for the user in console, but restricts to edit any config of it.(happy with that)

But dev user is then able to do deployments to the **prod** stage. I was indeed hoping for an arn like,

`"arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1::/restapis/6mvx7om366/deployments/stages/dev"`

But looks like there isn't. Is there any work-around?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?